# How to have different page name than class name in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have started learning CakePHP 3 and my goal is to build a website in Persian language. AFAI understood the `bake` binary creates pages based on the class/table name convention. My question is how to make it somehow to show a Persian name instead of the class/table name which is obviously is in English.

I mean is there a way to override what shows as the name of a page to users rather than the class/table name?

For example in the official example there is a Bookmarks page but I want it to show the Persian translation of the word 'Bookmarks'.

Comment: I'm not sure, but it sounds like you're either looking at [Routing](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html) URLs in Persian to your controller/action or for [I18n and L10n](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html) to translate English pages to Persian.

Comment: You can also create Bake Templates, but that would be alot of work.. I think.. http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/bake/development.html

Answer (score 0):

To change title element use this in your view file.

```
$this->assign('title',  'BookmarkInYourLanguage');
```

or yo could use localization.